# Why won`t it paste #2 Object does not support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

Similar to in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?. I would like to copy and paste values but am receiving a Run-Time Error 438: Object does not support this property or method.  Unfortunately I am not doing my copy and paste in the same way as this other person so the answers do not apply to me

```
Sub precipitation()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim directory As String, fileName As String
directory = "C:\Working-Directory\Precipdata\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        sheetName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4)
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        Workbooks(fileName).Activate
                If Range("B1").Value = "GJOA HAVEN A" Then
                col = "B"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "TALOYOAK A" Then
                col = "E"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "GJOA HAVEN CLIMATE" Then
                col = "H"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "HAT ISLAND" Then
                col = "K"
                End If
                If Range("B1").Value = "BACK RIVER (AUT)" Then
                    col = "N"
                End If
            yr = Range("B27").Value
            lngth = (Range("B27").End(xlDown).Row)
       Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Activate
           Set rw = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:=DateValue("01/01/" & yr))
           r = rw.Row

       Workbooks(fileName).Worksheet(sheetName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col & r)
       Workbooks(fileName).Close
       fileName = Dir()
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

My error comes on the  Workbooks(fileName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy _
        Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Range(col & r) line

Thank you

Comment: Your linked "question" is simply the "How to ask" page.

Comment: What are the values of the variables `filename`, `sheetname`, `lngth`, `col` and `r` when it crashes?

Comment: `.Worksheet(sheetName)` should be `.Worksheets(sheetName)`

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheet(sheetName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Copy Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col & r)
```

with:

```
Workbooks(fileName).Activate
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheet(sheetName).Range("P27", "P" & lngth).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Macroforprecip.xlsm").Activate
worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range(col & r).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: THANK YOU! IT WORKED.  I am so relieved. I was stuck for approximately 2017 years. (give or take 2017 years)